# Finding column to perform lookup in based on column header text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for what column a title string is in e.g., "Burgers sold", in one spreadsheet it's in column 2, sometimes 3 and so on. So I want to create a find function to record to macros which find "burgers sold" and returns which column its in so that column and row number can be used for VLOOKUP.
i.e., `VLOOKUP("burgers sold", ...)` without the user having to find and select what column the burger sold is in

Thanks

Comment: INDEX and MATCH functions? https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Answer (score 0):

No need for a macro -- you can include finding the "Burgers sold" column in the VLOOKUP formula.

So if you have a VLOOKUP to find "blah" in your table A100:M100, change the third argument so that it is a MATCH function looking for "Burgers sold" in the column headers.

```
=VLOOKUP("blah",A1:M100,MATCH("Burgers sold",A1:M1,0),0)
```

This should find the appropriate column and return the data for it from the row with "blah" in column A.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for. Its returning a row number, would you know how to return the column number as well ie A,B ,C etc?

Comment: I think Ive found the solution. Thank you :)))